# mySQL extract number or string depending on value

Tags: mysql, string, casting, numbers

Please take a look at a table below:

[image]

I need "the last part" of "what I have" to be number if it's all number and string if it contains character.

In Excel I've achieved this with the following function (as shown above):

```
=IFERROR(VALUE(TEXT(D2;"0"));TEXT(D2;"0"))
```

However I want to do this in mySQL in order to compute more effectively.

I've "floated" somwhere around `CASE` with `CAST` or `CONVERT` and also `TRIM` functions, but I haven't been able to put up something sensical.

A nice "bonus" would be to extract "the part part" by looking for the last "*" character (so first "*" from right of the string) but no idea at all how to achieve that.

Comment: Note that one column of an SQL result can only have a single type, so either string *or* numerical. You can either return all values as strings in a single column, or return strings in one and numbers in another column. If you only want to trim away leading `0`s from numbers you can do that with `CASE`, or `UNION`, or...

Comment: Please  provide the CREATE TABLE statements and INSERT statements voor MySQL.. and not a image as data.

Answer (score 2):

Use SUBSTRING_INDEX.

**Query**

```
SELECT 
 CASE 
   WHEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(records.data, '_', -1) > 1 # is int check '00004949' returns 1
   THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(records.data, '_', -1) + 0 # converts '00004949' to 4949
   ELSE SUBSTRING_INDEX(records.data, '_', -1)
 END
  AS word   
FROM (
  SELECT "TRA_PL_NWL_EMA_NWLY_DAI_000_20170610_IN1_01P002bc" AS DATA
  UNION  
  SELECT "TRA_PL_NWL_EMA_NWLY_DAI_000_2017_0909_JET_00004949" AS DATA

) records
```

**Result**

```
word      
----------
01P002bc  
4949
```

Answer (score 0):

Following query will somewhat achieve the task:

```
SELECT 
case 
when SUBSTRING_INDEX(value, "_", -1) REGEXP('(^[0-9]+$)') 
     then Trim(Leading 0 from SUBSTRING_INDEX(value, "_", -1))
else SUBSTRING_INDEX(value, "_", -1)
end as Value
From yourtable;
```

[Click here for Demo](http://rextester.com/HUY55245)

Hope it helps!

Comment: What about things like `000000ASDF`?

Comment: @JimmyB I've edited the answer. It should work now. Thnx for the pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what u want.
At least it does what you have asked for.

```
SELECT 
CASE
    WHEN (
            CONVERT(
                substring(
                    txt,
                    LENGTH(txt) - LOCATE('_', REVERSE(txt))+2,
                    length(txt)
                )
                , signed integer
            )
        ) = 0
    THEN substring(
            txt,
            LENGTH(txt) - LOCATE('_', REVERSE(txt))+2,
            length(txt)
        ) 
    ELSE CONVERT(
                substring(
                    txt,
                    LENGTH(txt) - LOCATE('_', REVERSE(txt))+2,
                    length(txt)
                )
                , signed integer
            )
    END as NUMBER

from test.test
```

This is my test Table and result of SQL:

```
txt                         NUMBER
DA_DA_ADAD_ADAD_ADAD_asd123 asd123
DA_DA_ADAD_ADAD_ADAD_000123 123
DA_DA_ADAD_ADAD_ADAD_444    444
DA_DA_ADAD_ADAD_ADAD_bsd123 bsd123
DA_DA_ADAD_ADAD_ADAD_csd123 csd123
DA_DA_ADAD_ADAD_ADAD_dsd123 dsd123
```